# How to cancel a task that is waiting with a timeout without exceptions being thrown

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, pfx

When canceling a task that has a timeout (before the timeout has ended) using a cancel token an exception is thrown.  Example:

```
mytask.start();
bool didTaskRunInTime = mytask.wait(5 mins, _cancelToken);
```

Which means I cannot go on like below.

```
//was the task cancelled
if (_cancelToken.IsCancelRequested)
{
    // log cancel from user to file etc
}

if (didTaskRunInTime )
{
    int taskResult = myTask.Result;
    // log result to file
}
else if (!_cancelToken.IsCancelRequested)
{
    // Tell user task timed out , log a message etc
}
```

I will have to do all this in my catch block and my code is looking messy. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could call [`Task.WaitAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235645.aspx) with an array of *just* that task. Then you can act on the status of the task, however the method returns. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Task sleeper = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(100000));

        int index = Task.WaitAny(new[] { sleeper },
                                 TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        Console.WriteLine(index); // Prints -1, timeout

        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // Just a simple wait of getting a cancellable task
        Task cancellable = sleeper.ContinueWith(ignored => {}, cts.Token);

        // It doesn't matter that we cancel before the wait
        cts.Cancel();

        index = Task.WaitAny(new[] { cancellable },
                             TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        Console.WriteLine(index); // 0 - task 0  has completed (ish :)
        Console.WriteLine(cancellable.Status); // Cancelled
    }
}
```

Note that if the task is faulted, you should "observe" the exception in order to avoid it going bang when it's finalized :)

Comment: I think it will throw, WaitAny will aggregate all exceptions, you should even call wait after the waitAny (and maybe cancelling the others) in order to catch their exceptions.

Comment: thanks John. But waitany does not take a timeout. I have long running export that needs timeout handling.

Comment: @eFloh: `WaitAll` aggregates exceptions. `WaitAny` doesn't. See the sample code.

Comment: @Gullu: Yes it does (or at least can) - see my sample code :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: good to know, that means infact that after using waitAny, one has to ensure that alle other tasks' exceptions will be caught (e.g. using WaitAll)

Comment: @eFloh: Indeed. I believe the need to observe exceptions may be changing in .NET 5 though...

Comment: thanks Jon. Solution for sure. But now handling the exception is looking more readable and easy to maintain :-) Like Vlad has shown below.

Answer (score 3):

try to use OperationCanceledException

```
try
{           
    mytask.start();
    bool didTaskRunInTime = mytask.wait(5 mins, _cancelToken);

    if (didTaskRunInTime )
    {
        int taskResult = myTask.Result;
        //log result to file
    }
    else
    {
        // Tell user task timed out , log a message etc
    }
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    // log cancel from user to file et
}
```

Comment: that was what i was trying to avoid but I may have no choice. My reasoning was that if someone set a cancelToken and intends to cancel why the hell is this thing designed to throw an exception. thanks Vlad

Comment: There's no requirement to use exceptions here - see my answer for an example without a try/catch at all.