# Stopping Parallel.ForEach if one of threads performs more than N minutes

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I'm looking for a solution for stopping `Parallel.ForEach` if one of threads performs more than 2 minutes.

The next solution I think is not very good because of x2 extra threads:

```
Parallel.ForEach(items, (item, opt) =>
{
    var thread = new Thread(() => { /* a process */ });
    thread.Start();

    bool finished = thread.Join(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
    if (!finished)
    {
        thread.Abort();
        opt.Stop();
    }
});
```

Do you know a better solution for the issue?

Comment: I'd use an array of `Task` with a cancellation token and timeout. You may be asking too much of `Parallel.ForEach`. Its also very odd that you are using `Parallel.ForEach` to kick off threads that do work...

Comment: @RonBeyer, can you post a solution here using an array of `Task`?

Comment: Its not that simple because the work needs to be batched and broken into the tasks. It depends on how many items are in your `items` collection.

Comment: @RonBeyer, the collection has about 10^6 items. And time for calculation of one item can vary. Maybe you can suggest me a solution for tracking all active threads from the main thread?

Comment: Use `CancellationTokenSource` for the cancellation for the Tasks in this case, and set flag inside one task for being able to say which task is currently running

Comment: `Thread.Abort` is dangerous and could leave your program in a corrupted state, is it possible to re-write your long running code using a `CancelationToken` and have it cooperatively cancel?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, No, it's impossible. Functionality of a process is too hard to modify. And I don't need to cancel other threads if one of them is performed too long. All items are independent.

Comment: You should really read through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort Even if all you do is abort a single thread you can still screw a lot of stuff up. For example a big problem is if your code uses `lock` the locks will not be released if the abort happened inside the lock!. The only "Safe" way to do a non cooperative abort is move the code to a separate exe then call `Process.Kill` on the exe, but this adds a lot of overhead.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I understand you. I will try to refactor code for using a `CancelationToken`. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Added some links in answer

Comment: Related: [Forcefully terminate thread generated by Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066319/forcefully-terminate-thread-generated-by-parallel-foreach).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to note that `Parallel` class **will not create** a thread for each of your item, it will use default `ThreadPool`, which has by default number of threads equal to processor's cores count. Other problem in your code is that you do not stop all the tasks after 2 minutes of working, you only cancel the one which you've waited for two minutes.

I suggest you remove the `Thread` usage from your code, and create an array of `Tasks` with [single `CancellationToken` for them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) with [a Timeout for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155760.aspx) or with [a timeout for `TaskFactory`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682231/213550), and [start them all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155759.aspx). Also your code should explicitly check the token for cancellation pending.

So your code could be something like this:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
// two minutes in milliseconds
cts.CancelAfter(2000 * 60);

var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    // this is needed because of closures work in C#
    var localItem = item;
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => 
        { /* a process with a localItem here */ 
            // this check should be repeated from time to time in your calculations
            if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
    // all tasks has only one token
    , cts.Token)

}
// this will cancel all tasks after 2 minutes from start
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
// this will cancel all tasks if one of them will last more than 2 minutes
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

---

**Update:**

As you said that the each item is independent, you can create `CancellationTokenSource` for each task, but, as @ScottChamberlain noted, in this case too many tasks will run in the same time. You can [write your own `TaskScheduler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx), use some [`Semafor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) (or [it's slim version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx)) or simply use the `Parallel` class with [`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784105.aspx) correctly set.

Comment: One problem with this, you will now spin up `items.Count` tasks all at once (the op noted there are 10^6 items in the collection). the original `Parallel.ForEach` method would rate limit itself. A littile reorganizing plus a `SemaphoreSlim` you could re-create `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.